# Make android app icon available to other applications

Tags: android, icons, manifest

I would like my application icon to be available to other applications.

I understand this is a bit unclear so will try explain:

Applications such as Astros program manager lists applications with their icon.  For all apps this is the correct icon as on the launcher, except mine which is displaying the standard android icon.  I have set my icon as the manifest using: `android:icon="@drawable/runninglate"`

This works on the launcher but Astro still shows the default icon from when I create the project (which I deleted a long time ago).  I have also tried renaming my icon file to icon.png in case this was a standard.  This also failed to work.

I am clearly doing something wrong, or have missed a setting somewhere, can some one point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a caching issue.  I re-flashed my phone today for an update and the correct Icon was shown using the same APK as I was using when it wasn't showing.  Maybe a clear data on the displaying app was all that was required!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your icon in the `<application>` element, perhaps in addition to having it in the `<activity>` element of the activity that should appear in the Launcher.

Comment: Sorry it's been so long:
I have the android:icon element in both <application> and <activity>, no luck. I must clearly be doing something wrong no other apps on my Hero suffer the same issue.